# Proving $p\iff q$ when $p$ is true.

Tags: logic

To prove $p\iff q$ when $p$ is true, do I only have to show $q$ must be true?

Since $p$ is true, the only possible cases are '$p$ is true and $q$ is true' and '$p$ is true and $q$ is false'. So I only have to show $q$ must be true. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, that is correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Here is the [truth table](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=truth%20table%20p%3D%3E%28q%3D%3E%28p%3C%3D%3Eq%29%29):

[image]

Here is a formal proof:

[image]